# python: pandas method to know a number of tables in a html

Tags: python, pandas

to read the tables in a html file I am using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
url="......html'
df=pd.read_html(url)

for i in range(0,10):
   print(df[i])
```

This works. But I am processing large amount of data and not sure how many tables are present. is there a way we can know using any package in python/pandas to know the total number of tables in a given html

Comment: why dont you try beautifulsoup4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do with pandas or [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/),

let's say you are parsing this,

```
url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States'

import pandas as pd
dfs=pd.read_html(url)

len(dfs)
out[]: 18 # this url has 18 tables
```

you can also do the same with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), and [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/), more faster.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

len(soup.find_all('table'))

out[]: 18 #no of tables.
```